# Escape Velocity and its effect on the atmosphere

Tags: newtonian-gravity, atmospheric-science, kinetic-theory, gas, escape-velocity

I’ve been doing some world building and wound up with a bit of a physics puzzle that’s stumped me. So rather than a long winded explanation I’ll simply state the primary parameters.

Under otherwise “earth standard” conditions, what effect would changing the escape velocity have on the atmosphere? Surface is still 1g, atmospheric mix unchanged, etc.

So far all I have found is basic theory regarding kinetic energy of gasses with respect to molecular masses and how loss rates differ with respect to molecular mass. Jean’s escape, etc.

Is this really the only thing that would change about the atmosphere? We would loose less of it? No subtle increase in the density at the highest layers as less escapes? No change in the limit/value of any properties?

Comment: How (by what method) do you change the escape velocity?  Also, do you increase it or decrease it?

Comment: @puppetsock it’s proportional to mass but not in the same way as surface gravity is proportional, as a result larger less dense planets can maintain surface 1g with increased escape velocity. I’ve run numbers from earth standard up past 5x normal escape velocity.

Comment: So with a larger less-dense planet, what happens to the rate of change of density of the atmosphere as altitude increases?